# Datetimefield, EmailField is not callable and PrimaryKeyRelatedField has unexpected argument

Tags: python, pycharm

I encounter a problem either with my pycharm or virtualenv or system.

I am using ubuntu, Pycharm as IDE ,python 3.6.3 and a given list of libraries

```
dataclasses==0.6
Django==2.1.7
django-cors-headers==2.4.0
django-currentuser==0.3.3
django-filter==2.0.0
django-localflavor==2.1
django-stubs==0.9.0
djangorestframework==3.9.2
djangorestframework-camel-case==0.2.0
djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0
djangorestframework-stubs==0.3.0
future==0.16.0
mypy==0.670
mypy-extensions==0.4.1
mysqlclient==1.3.13
Pillow==5.4.1
PyJWT==1.6.4
pytz==2018.5
serializers==0.2.4
typed-ast==1.3.1
typing-extensions==3.7.2
```

My pycharm rports my a series of problems:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The project used work fine in the morning but after a few hours I started suffering this problems. I have tried to restart my Pychar, Pycharm reinstallation and I even made a new virtualenviroment...

I have no idea how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed those libraries:

```
dataclasses==0.6
future==0.16.0
mypy==0.670
mypy-extensions==0.4.1
serializers==0.2.4
typed-ast==1.3.1
typing-extensions==3.7.2
```

Some of them were suggested by Pycharm. I installed it and started expecting above issues.